# Drawing a spring ring with 3 masses

Tags: texmaker, draw

I'm trying to figure out how to draw the following using LaTeX:

[image: screenshot from given example]
How can I draw a system with round springs?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

• Note this is a Q&A site, not a please do this for me service. What do you have so far.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. It would be better if you tell you what you have already tried using a [minimum working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/28557). Also from the image you posted, its quite difficult to understand what you really are looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE. There is [an ongoing discussion on "do-it-for-me" questions](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7926/explicitly-indicate-the-reasons-why-answering-a-just-do-it-for-me-question), which you may want to read. For newcomers sometimes exceptions are made, but it would be great if you could consider trying to ask more meaningful questions. As pointed out by nidhin, it is hard to tell what you want to draw, here is a guess.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick,decoration={coil,segment
length=pi*8cm/72,amplitude=5pt},decorate,xscale=-1] (0,0) circle (4cm);
\node[fill,minimum size=12mm,label=above right:$M$] (M) at (180:4){};
\node[fill,minimum size=6mm,label=right:$m$,rotate=45] (m1) at (45:4){};
\node[fill,minimum size=6mm,label=right:$m$,rotate=-45] (m2) at (-45:4){};
\draw[thick] (90:3) -- ++ (0,3);
\draw[-latex] (-0.5,5) arc(180:405:0.5 and 0.25) node[above right]{$\omega$}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]